# How can i clear empty array in multiple file upload array

Tags: php

I have encountered such a problem. and This is the solution.

```
$file_count=count($_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["tmp_name"]);
        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            if($_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["error"][$i]==0){
                $sozlesme_array["name"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["name"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["type"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["type"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["tmp_name"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["error"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["error"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["size"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["size"][$i];
            }
} print_r($sozlesme_array);
```

...

When uploading multiple files, if one of the files is empty it returns such an error in the array.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => file.pdf
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => application/pdf
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => C:\wamp64\tmp\php2FE0.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 150728
        )

)
```

I want to delete empty elements in the array.
https://indir360.com/

[son dakika](https://www.turkiyehaberi.com/)
[phpstorm indir](https://indir360.com/indir/phpstorm)

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do here or what's exactly your question, maybe you've just forgot to initialize `$sozlesme_array` propperly.

Comment: When uploading multiple files, if one of the files is empty it returns such an error in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unset` to clear an array:

```
unset($sozlesme_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the file name like following :

```
$file_count=count($_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["tmp_name"]);
        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            if(isset($_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["name"][$i]) && !empty($_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["name"][$i])){
                $sozlesme_array["name"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["name"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["type"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["type"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["tmp_name"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["error"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["error"][$i];
                $sozlesme_array["size"][]=$_FILES["sozlesme_pdf"]["size"][$i];
            }
} print_r($sozlesme_array);
```